# Issue with writing in my sqlite database after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a sign up interface that takes a user name, email and password to sign up. But somehow, it seems it does not write into the database when I want to sign up a new user.
It will create a new line in the database, but with NULL assigned to name and email, as shown below.
[image: db]

Any idea what I am missing here ?

EDIT : the code for resp. my user.rb, user_controller.rb and usershelper.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts
    attr_accessor :name, :email
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase if email}
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive:false}

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
end
```

#

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "welcome to the app!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render :new 
      end
  end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
```

#

```
module UsersHelper
    def gravatar_for(user)
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.to_s.downcase)
        gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
        image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
    end
end
```

EDIT2 : additional infos

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

[image]

Comment: Care to post your code? It's hard to identify what's wrong without having anything to analyze.

Comment: Also, paste the logs of a POST to your create action coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
attr_accessor :name, :email
```

It is overriding the database attributes, so that the values get written to @name and @email instead of being saved to the database.